# Call async code from sync impl of trait in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am developing my first toy project that consists in a simple API with the Rocket framework. But I am stuck with a very basic need and I would love to have you insights on how to solve it.

For some endpoint, I need to call an external REST API, so I am using the `reqwest` crate to do so. I prefer doing it async because I expect my API to have a lot of concurrent requests on that endpoint.

On the other side, I implement the whole think using clean/hexagonal architecture guidelines and then I use traits as a kind of interface. This helps for testing and mocking amongst other things.

How does it looks like:

```rust
pub trait DataFetcher {
  fn fetch_data(path: String) -> Result<String, Box<dyn sts::error::Error>>,
}

pub struct DataProvider {
}

impl DataProvider {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    // constructor here.
  }
}

impl DataFetcher for DataProvider {
  pub fetch_data(path: String) -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // call to external REST API should be here.
  }
}
```

The problem comes here: async trait methods are not supported in Rust 2018. Here are my guesses:

1. Stop using traits
2. Use Async_traits crate (experimental)
3. Other ?

What is you advice? Do you have some example projects that I can be inspired from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`async-trait`](https://docs.rs/async-trait/) crate is definitely not experimental. It is one of the most widely used crates, and is the standard solution for async fns in traits.

However, I would not use traits if you don't need the abstraction. This just complicates the code.